# Rails activeadmin new action with related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In my rails app i use active admin, now i have such model (only part)

```
class Distributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :co****ime
  has_many :price_lists
  has_many :other_products_cross_lists
end

class OtherProductsCrossList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cross***pe_id
  belongs_to :product_type
  belongs_to :distributor
  belongs_to :accumulator
  belongs_to :oil
end

class Accumulator < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :capa***age
    has_many :other_products_cross_lists
end
```

For security, i *** attr...

So if i create a new Accumulator, i also need so, that with accumulator field's i see OtherProductsCrossList fields, and create accumulator, and cross for it, also i need to do such button :more, so if i need to create more than one cross for this accumulator it will do this. Also note, that id and refferertable_id must be same... How to do this? Form with another form for create action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a complicated/nested form, I don't think Active Admin is a good choice. You have to learn its DSL and have to face its bugs.

And writting your own implementation is:

- not so hard with ERB/HAML's help, ERB/HAML is more easy to use than ActiveAdmin's View DSL.
- very flexible, you are free to change the pages(CSS) and the models.

I tried ActiveAdmin for several projects, but very soon I abandoned it, because not only it gives me too few benefits/convenience, but also gives me too many difficulties to make my own customization.

To me, Active Admin is similar with the "Scaffold", but much worse.

Comment: but also is it a good practice to write own new create etc methods and own routes?